# Two 12v 1A DC power sources using a 1 gang switch?

Tags: switches, dc

I'm wondering if it is possible to connect two 12v 1A DC power sources to a single switch? And if so, how would such a schematic look like. The two power sources will then power their own things.

Comment: By 1-gang, do you mean the kind of switch that's used in household wiring, in a 1-gang electrical box?  That's the only situation where I commonly hear "gang" used to refer to switches, and you can indeed get double pole switches (basically two switches with a single handle) rated to interrupt 12VDC @1A in that form factor.  If you meant single pole, then refer to the other answers.

Comment: Exactly that Nate! However I have two fans I'd like to switch on and off with the same switch!

Comment: In that case, look for a switch capable of switching 240V loads -- it'll be double pole since there's two hots to switch for 240V equipment in North America.

Comment: Although, I did some quick looking and finding a two-pole switch that's also DC rated seems difficult.  Have you considered using relays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not a good idea unless you have a really good reason to do it exactly this way. Let's look at why:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTbvI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you simulate this circuit, then you will see that the loads will be supplied only when SW1 is closed. However, there are two problems with it:

1. If V1 and V2 are *not* exactly equal in voltage (real power supplies are not ideal voltage sources!) then, when the switch is open, the series arrangement of V1 and V2 will supply the *difference* between the two voltages to the two loads *in series* — and that's if the lower-voltage supply doesn't react oddly to "sinking" current (current flowing into + and out of −). If this difference voltage is small, then the stray path might not do any harm, but what happens if one of the power supplies fails or has its input disconnected, or is overloaded? You may damage one of the power supplies, or the circuit may become "on" without the switch being closed (with 12V across both loads in series).

   And also, if while the circuit is on one of the power supplies is overloaded by its load, then the supply will reduce its voltage or cut out entirely, giving the wrong voltage for both loads again.

   You could fix this problem by adding series diodes on the positive lines from both power supplies to prevent reverse current flow. But then you lose some voltage and waste some power in the diode, unless you use an active “ideal diode” circuit.
2. You'll notice I haven't labeled anything “ground” in this schematic.  **Where would it go?** In particular, if the ground is on the negative side of the 12V, your loads and supplies have common ground/shield connections with *any other equipment* then they might by some path bypass the switch (and then not only is the switch ineffective, but you're putting supply current through paths not intended to carry it).

So, if all you want to do is, say, power some lights or similar completely-isolated equipment that can tolerate stray voltages and be replaced if something goes weird, then it might be okay to do this. But unless you have some sort of special requirement ("the user should connect these two sockets with a single wire to activate both circuits" or something) — just use a DPST switch.

---

A note about the conditions under which the above description is true:

- It doesn't matter whether the loads are equal.
- It doesn't matter whether the current rating of the power supplies is equal (but if they aren't and one of them gets overloaded, you'll have problems as described above).
- The two power supplies *do* have to be equal voltage; it can't work even as much as it does if you have different voltage supplies.

Comment: Super awesome answer. I am in awe at how well you explained this!

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. You need a DPST switch — use one pole for each of the supply/load combinations.